# How can I print out multiple queried objects via html template

Tags: django, view

```
class License(models.Model):
   agency = models.ForeignKey(Agency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   contact_person = models.ManyToManyField(ContactPerson())
   description = models.CharField("License Description", max_length=250)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   renewal_frequency = models.CharField("Renewal Frequency", max_length=20)
   sop = models.FileField(upload_to="sop")

  

class Timeline(models.Model):
   license = models.ForeignKey(License, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   last_renewed = models.DateField()
   due_date = models.DateField()
   lpo = models.FileField(upload_to="lpo")
   comment = models.TextField("Comment", max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
   report = models.FileField(upload_to="reports", null=True,blank=True)

  def home(request):
     title = "Licences"
     agencies = Agency.objects.all()
     agent =Agency.objects.get(pk=1)
     licenses = License.objects.all()
     for license.id in licenses:
     timeline = Timeline.objects.select_related().filter(license_id = 
     license.id).order_by('-id')[:1]
     print(timeline)
     


     {% for renewal in timeline %}
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                          <a href="{% url 'licenseupdate' renewal.license.id %}" 
                           class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
                          <a href="{% url 'removeobject' renewal.license.id %}" 
                           class="btn btn-danger"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></a>
                        </td>
                        <td> <a href="{% url 'timelines' renewal.license.id %}"> 
                         {{renewal.license.description}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{renewal.license.location}}</td>
                        <td>{{renewal.license.renewal_frequency}}</td>
                        <td>{{renewal.last_renewed}}</td>
                        <td>{{renewal.due_date}}</td>
```

i am trying to pring out all my License models with the latest timeline related to it, but the for loop only returns one license. only one license gets displayed to my template.

Comment: You slice the timeline queryset to only get one result `[:1]`, remove the slice?

Comment: when i print timeline i'm getting four querry objects, that slice is surposed to return just one timeline for each license..

Comment: Should it be possible to have multiple Timelines for each License? If not, then you have a deeper problem....

Comment: Your home view function doesn't look complete to me - you're not passing any context into a call to create a response object. In any case it would make more sense to loop over the license objects and refer to timeline_set.first in the template.

Comment: thats how it is, one license has multiple timelines, thats why i had the foregnkey in my timeline model. can i access the timelines from the license object...?

Comment: i passed the context to my template, only that i didnt capture the whole home view

Comment: <QuerySet [<Timeline: Timeline object (3)>]>
<QuerySet [<Timeline: Timeline object (5)>]>
<QuerySet [<Timeline: Timeline object (8)>]>
<QuerySet [<Timeline: Timeline object (9)>]>
<QuerySet [<Timeline: Timeline object (11)>]>
this is the return am getting when i print timeline